# Compare two dictionaries and store the result in other

Tags: c#, dictionary

How to compare two dictionaries, my dictionaries are as follows

```
  Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
  dic.Add("One", "One");
  dic.Add("Two", "Two");

  Dictionary<string, string> dic1 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
  dic1 .Add("One", "One");
  dic1 .Add("Two", "Two");
  dic1 .Add("Three", "Three");
```

I tried some thing like `var diff = dic1.Where(x => x.Value != dic[x.Key]).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);` but I am getting the exception as the key's doesn't match so can some one help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will give you the  difference,

```
var resultDic = dic1.Except(dic).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    private void Comparer(Dictionary<string, string> dic, Dictionary<string, string> dic1)
    {
        var diff = dic.Except(dic1).Concat(dic1.Except(dic));
    }
```